# how do I use Axios to post to a database in a form?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { config } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import "./AddFolder.css";

export default class AddFolder extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      textarea: "",
    };
  }

  handleCancelBtn() {
    window.history.back();
  }
  updateName(n) {
    console.log("updateName, ran: " + n + "  type is: " + typeof n);
    this.setState({ name: { value: n } });
  }
  updateTextarea(area) {
    console.log("updateTextarea, ran: " + area);
    this.setState({ textarea: { value: area } });
  }
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("handleSubmit, ran");
    const { name } = this.state;
    try {
      axios.post(
        `${config.API_ENDPOINT}/folders`,
        {
          name,
        }.then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          console.log(res.data);
          window.location = "/retrieve"; //This line of code will redirect you once the submission is succeed
        })
      );
      console.log("folder created");
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("there was an error: " + e.message);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form className="addfolder-form" onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
        <h2>Add Folder</h2>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="name">name:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="name-input"
            name="name"
            id="name"
            onChange={(e) => this.updateName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="text-area">content: </label>
          <textarea
            id="text-area"
            name="text-area"
            rows="4"
            cols="50"
            onChange={(e) => this.updateTextarea(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="button-group">
          <button
            type="reset"
            className="addfolder-btn"
            onClick={this.handleCancelBtn}
          >
            nevermind
          </button>
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="addfolder-btn"
            onClick={this.handleSubmit}
          >
            save
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

on this code `const { name } = this.state;` i get an error of:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

why is it undefined and how can I post data to my local storage which is stored in  ${config.API_ENDPOINT}/folders`, ?

i am trying to add the form inputs into the /folders endpoint using axios, so far the inputs are working, but when i try to submit it, i get the error above. i know i dont have textarea input there yet, but i am testing the name input.

Comment: For the methods in class components, you should use arrow functions or bind the functions in the constructor. A better option would be to use functional components and hooks.

Comment: I can see one syntax error. `}.then(...)`. Is it a typo?

Comment: yea it was a typo, i took it off

Answer (score 0):

"this" is undefined in the handleSubmit function. Like jayce said you have to bind the funtion in the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    name: "",
    textarea: "",
  };
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
```